# How to put a floating action button in a tableView in swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, floating-action-button

I am trying to use an floating action button in iOS to impose on a table view so that I can add items in the tableview with that . please help me with the code.

Comment: you can use https://cocoapods.org/pods/KCFloatingActionButton

Comment: Briefly, the easiest solution is to put the button in the view containing the tableview.  That way you don't have to worry about translation as the tableview moves.  This is the basic approach taken by Arindam's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code for it. It has been done without using storyboard.

TableView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let nameArray = ["India","Usa","UK"]

    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return table
    }()



    let btnFloating : UIButton = {
        let floating = UIButton()
        floating.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        floating .backgroundColor = .cyan
        floating.setTitle("ADD", for: .normal)
        return floating
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.addSubview(btnFloating)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        setuoConstrain()
        //Set the action of add button
        btnFloating.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAddTapp(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func setuoConstrain(){
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        //Constrain For Button :
        btnFloating.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
        btnFloating.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
        btnFloating.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        btnFloating.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -36).isActive = true


    }

    //This function is for add button . What action you want , can put inside this function
    @objc func btnAddTapp(sender: UIButton){
        print("add button tapp")
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let  nameCell = NameTableCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "NameTableCell")
        nameCell.lblName.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        return nameCell
    }
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class NameTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    let lblName: UILabel = {
        let name = UILabel()
        name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return name
    }()



    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(lblName)

        constrain()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func constrain(){
        lblName.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupFloatingActionButton() {

    Floaty.global.button.buttonImage = UIImage(named: "icon-social")
    Floaty.global.button.buttonColor = UIColor.white
    let facebookItem = FloatyItem()
    facebookItem.icon = UIImage(named: "icon-facebook")
    facebookItem.title = "Facebook"
    Floaty.global.button.addItem(item: facebookItem)

    let gmailItem = FloatyItem()
    Floaty.global.button.addItem("Gmail", icon: UIImage(named: "icon-gmail"), handler: {_
        in
        print("Gmail Button tapp")
    })   

    let twitterItem = FloatyItem()
    Floaty.global.button.addItem("Twitter", icon: UIImage(named: "icon-twitter"), handler: {_ in
        print("twitter Button tapp")
    })

    //Floaty.global.button.animationSpeed = 0.50
    Floaty.global.button.openAnimationType = .fade
    //Floaty.global.button.rotationDegrees = 90.00
    Floaty.global.show()
}
```